# Jumpy toolbar items in NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I tried to use a custom view as the navigation title inside a `NavigationView`. Every time when the detail view is popped up, the toolbar items are always resized quickly in a second. I also tested adding a button there as ToolbarItem, the same. Am I misuing something?

```
struct ContentView: View {        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Detail")
                    .toolbar {
                        VStack {
                            Text("title")
                            Text("subtitle")
                        }
                    }
            } label: {
                Text("Detail")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @ChrisR Sorry forgot that. Added.

Comment: Works fine with me in simulator. what device / version are you using?

Comment: 15.4.1 with iPhone 12 Pro. Not reproduced on 15.4 iPhone 12. Seems just one more SwiftUI bug :)

Comment: It happens to me as well in an iPhone X with iOS 15.5. The weird thing is it doesn't happen either on Simulator (iOS 15.5 and 16) or in physical devices with iOS 16 I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing Toolbar item inside .toolbar.

```
.toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { //You're missing this.
            VStack {
                Text("title")
                Text("subtitle")
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work on my side. :(

Comment: It'd work, I've added gif as well, I can share my code if you want to. It's pretty simple and one liner.

Comment: I see. That makes me doubt it's some bug related to the device/version.

Comment: If you're on iOS 14 then it might be, I faced few bugs in iOS 14 only and were working fine in iOS 15+